# How do I access multiple state in parent from child component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parameter-passing

I have a Parent screen "Filters" that show a series of multiple options from which the user can save and set his own search preferences as he/she wishes.

As the list of options grow, I keep them in an array and render it via an iterated Child component .

In the Parent I also keep state hooks for each options as I need to know all settings in order to run the correct search query.

**MY PROBLEM**
I'm struggling to refer to the state and setter of the hooks from child to parent. I need to know in the child component if each option state is true or false to make some CSS changes.

If I don't use a child component I can obviously access the hooks and all works fine however I end up with repetitive tons of code and it is not very elegant.

Here's is my parent:

```
// My array of filter options
const filterOptions = [
  { id: "0", name: "gin" },
  { id: "1", name: "rum" },
  { id: "2", name: "vodka" },
  { id: "3", name: "brandy" },
  { id: "4", name: "whisky" },
  { id: "5", name: "champagne" }
];

// My Parent component
const CocktailSearchScreen = (props) => {

  // My state hooks
  const [gin, setGin] = useState(false);
  const [rum, setRum] = useState(false);
  const [vodka, setVodka] = useState(false);
  const [whiskey, setWhiskey] = useState(false);
  const [champagne, setChampagne] = useState(false);

 // my callback function triggered by Child component
  const filterSetter = (option) => {
    switch (option) {
      case "gin":
        setGin(!gin);
        break;
      case "rum":
        setRum(!rum);
        break;
      case "vodka":
        setVodka(!vodka);
        break;
      case "whiskey":
        setWhiskey(!whiskey);
        break;
      default:
        Alert.alert("Option not found");
    }
  };

  // I'me rendering my list of option using the Child component <FilterItem />
  {filterOptions.map((item, index) => {
         return (
           <FilterItem
               id={item.id}
               filterName={item.name}                
               onItemSelection={filterSetter}
           />
          );
    })}
}
```

And here is my Child component...

```
const FilterItem = (props) => {
  // parent callback function - I set the hook by passing the item name(value)
  const itemHandler = async () => {
    props.onItemSelection(props.filterName);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={itemHandler} key={props.id}>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.modalText,
          props.filterName
            ? { backgroundColor: Colors.accentColor, borderRadius: 4 }
            : null,
        ]}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.modalTxt,
            props.filterName ? styles.selectedTextStyle : null,
          ]}
        >
          {props.filterName}
        </Text>
        <Icon
          name={"check"}
          size={20}
          style={[
            styles.drawerItem,
            props.filterName ? styles.selectedTextStyle : null,
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

In this line of code within the Child

```
props.filterName ? styles.selectedTextStyle : null,
```

I should check the item hook's state and if TRUE assign the style styles.selectedTextStyle instead of checking the item name

I guess I need to find a way to pass the state and/or setter to  as props.
In a case of 1 individual state it would be simple like this

```
<FilterItem {state} {setState} />
```

but in my case I have many hooks.

**NOTE**
all my item names are the same as hooks values, not sure if that helps.
i.e.

```
{ id: "0", name: "gin" },
const [gin, setGin] = useState(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the state as object. Something like:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  gin: false,
  rum: false,
  vodka: false,
  champagne: false,
  whiskey: false,
});
```

then you can simplify filterSetter function:

```js
const filterSetter = (option) => {
  Object.keys(state).includes(option)
    ? setState({ ...state, [option]: !state[option] })
    : Alert.alert("Option not found");
};
```

In order to know the status of the filter you could pass a prop like `isFilterActive`:

```js
<FilterItem
  isFilterActive={state[item.name]}
  filterName={item.name}
  onItemSelection={filterSetter}
  id={item.id}
/>;
```

On the `FilterItem` component you can set the proper style this way:

```
props.isFilterActive ? styles.selectedTextStyle : null,
```

Comment: @Fererico Wow that was an amazing answer, opened up a new world on how to reference and pass params. Many Thanks!